# How to test a component that uses an apollo client Reactive Var

Tags: jestjs, react-hooks, enzyme, apollo-client

How do you unit test  (with `jest` and `enzyme`)  a functional component that uses the `useReactiveVar` hook?

Should I mock the `useReactiveVar` hook with `jest`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can mock whole apollo client in each test to give different responses. I mean:

```
jest.mock('@apollo/client', () => ({
    makeVar: () => {
      return {};
    },
    useReactiveVar: () => {
      return { account: { name: 'Test' } };
    },
  }));
```

But this is helpful only when testing component that use only one reactiveVar at all.